# What does rosrun do internally?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this tutorial - https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

Out of curiosity, I ran the listener using `rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py` but ran the talker manually.
That is, I changed directory to beginner tutorials, and ran, `python talker.py`.

I didn't expect it to work, but it did. The nodes are communicating with each other.

Is that a fluke, or will this always work?
Is rosrun's job only to find the correct node based on the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, or does it do something else as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339462/what-does-rosrun-do-internally?/) by [Raghuram Krishnaswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/50120/raghuram-krishnaswami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will always work. Rosrun's only job is exactly what you said: It searches a couple of directories for the correct node and run it, nothing more. You can get more info on what directories it's searching, and what executable it ends up running, by specifying the `--debug` flag:

```
$ source ~/ros-kinetic/devel/setup.bash
$ rosrun --debug imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node
[rosrun] Looking in catkin libexec dirs: 
/home/martin/ros-kinetic/devel/lib/imu_filter_madgwick
/home/martin/ros-kinetic/devel/share/imu_filter_madgwick
/home/martin/ros-kinetic/src/imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick
[rosrun] Looking in rospack dir: /home/martin/ros-kinetic/src/imu_tools/imu_filter_madgwick
[rosrun] Searching for imu_filter_node with permissions /111
[rosrun] Running  /home/martin/ros-kinetic/devel/lib/imu_filter_madgwick/imu_filter_node
```

If you want to dig deeper, here's the full source code of rosrun (just about 100 lines of bash code): https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/2b307e1854ebf3954a5b4110f891278f555e79a6/tools/rosbash/scripts/rosrun

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2019-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2